# filename autocomplete in reverse order

Tags: autocomplete, fish

I would like to know if there is a way to tell fish to reverse the output of autocomplete for certain commands and even better for certain repositories (I doubt even more about this one). I looked into the complete command but I believe it's different to what I want.

So if I have a folder A like this (hopefully that's clear enough)

A

> A1
>
> > A1A
> >  A1B
> >  A1C
> >  etc...

> A2
>
> > A2A
> >  A2B
> > etc...

And I run let's say the "cd" command in the A folder like so
`cd A<TAB>`
I get this autocomplete prompt

```
> cd A
A1/ A2/
```

So is there a way to actually get

```
> cd A
A2/ A1/
```

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a way to tell fish to reverse the output of autocomplete for certain commands and even better for certain repositories (I doubt even more about this one)

In short: Basically no.

In longer: You *can* provide completions that keep their order with `complete --keep-order`, but that would require modifying basically the entire completion script for a command, and fish provides no facilities to apply that to its built-in file completions, so you'd have to provide the files through script.